# Get checkedtextview checked positions

Tags: android, listadapter

I have a ListActivity where I make this

```
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(Phone.CONTENT_URI,
            new String[] { Phone._ID, Phone.DISPLAY_NAME }, null, null,
            null);
    startManagingCursor(cursor);
    String[] columns = new String[] { Phone.DISPLAY_NAME };
    int[] to = new int[] { R.id.name_row };
    ListAdapter mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
            R.layout.contact_list_row, cursor, columns, to);
    this.setListAdapter(mAdapter);
```

which binds my contacts names no my listadapter. Every row is a checkedtext view, so know I want to create a method to retrieve my checked items, but I can't get it to work. Can some one point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure about checkboxes but I've done this for buttons and other elements and, having had a quick look around, I think this method is the same.

Insert `android:onClick="methodName"` in the checkbox element layout XML.

in your code have something similar to this function:

```
//Called from XML
public void methodName(View view) {
    int cursorPosition= getListView().getPositionForView(view);
    Bundle itemData = (Bundle) mAdapter.getItem(cursorPosition);
    // do something with data
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So I found my way. The problem was that I was using checked_positions.get(i) instead of checked_positions.valueAt(i).

```
            ListView lv = getListView();
            SparseBooleanArray checked_positions = lv.getCheckedItemPositions();
            for (int i = 0; i < checked_positions.size(); i++) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Checked " + i + " Value " + checked_positions.valueAt(i));
                if (checked_positions.valueAt(i)) {
                    Cursor ctv = (Cursor) lv.getItemAtPosition(checked_positions.keyAt(i));
                }
            }
```